# Widget where it can make changes to the container

Tags: plugins, widgets, customization

Is it possible to create a widget where it can make changes to the container?

An example is like this:

```
    <!--- widget-container --->
    <div class="wdget">
       <div class="textwidget">
         <!--TOPWIDGET-->
         <div style="clear:both;"></div> <!--- <=== See this =--->
         <!--/TOPWIDGET-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--- /widget-container --->
```

be like this:

```
    <!--- widget-container --->
         <div style="clear:both;"></div> <!--- <=== See this =--->
    <div class="wdget">
       <div class="textwidget">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--- /widget-container --->
```

or something else like that.

If I use this:

```
    register_sidebar(
       array(
          'before_widget' => "<div style=\"clear:both;\">"
                            ."</div><div id=\"%1$s\" class=\"widget %2$s\">",
          'after_widget' => "</div>"
       )
    );
```

will replace all widget, not just a widget that I want.

My main goal is that I can give `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` element among a widget that I can treat as a widget, so it is easily to move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend that. Much easier to use a [clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) to force clearing and just add that style to your widget. Clearfix hacks are transparent: it doesn't matter if they happen on all elements there is no visible difference, other than clear floats.

Somewhere in your themes `style.css`:

```
.widget:before,
.widget:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.widget:after {
    clear: both;
}

.widget {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

You can, of course, put that anywhere. You could hook into `wp_head` or `wp_footer` and spit out a custom style tag just for that.  Or you could be more specific. For instance if you're registering a custom widget, you could add a clearfix hack to that specifically by classname.

Alternatively, if you really want to just add a clear div to a certain widget, you can hook into `dynamic_sidebar_params`. Your hooked function will receive a single argument: an array of sidebar params -- including `before_widget` and `after_widget` and `widget_name` which will be the second argument you passed to `parent::__construct` when you [register the widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Developing_Widgets).  Something like this:

```
<?php
add_filter('dynamic_sidebar_params', 'wpse90953_sidebar_params');
function wpse90953_sidebar_params($widget_params)
{
    if (!empty($widget_params['widget_name']) && 'your_widget_name' === $widget_params['widget_name']) {
        $widget_params['before_widget'] = '<div style="clear:both"></div>' . $widget_params['before_widget'];
    }

    return $widget_params;
}
```

Comment: Good idea. But unfortunately, `['widget_name']` can be problematic when used in multilingual theme. In addition, your script lacking closing function `empty()` and `$widget_params` used in index 0. But off the top of all, thank you for your help, it really helped me.

Comment: `$widget_params` used in index 0, so this supposed to be `$widget_params[0]['widget_name']` and `$widget_params[0]['before_widget']` (I'm sorry, my comment previously incomplete :D ).